# ui date picker not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, datepicker, placeholder

[image]When i was tried before this time its worked fine but now am following same process its not working

```html
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=txtDateOfBirth.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-50:+0"
    });
    $("#<%=txtDateOfBirth.ClientID %>").datepicker({ autoSize: true });
    //getter
    var autoSize = $("#<%=txtDateOfBirth.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "autoSize");
    //setter
    $("#<%=txtDateOfBirth.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "autoSize", true);
    $('#<%=imgDateOfBirth.ClientID %>').css({ 'cursor': 'pointer', "vertical-align": 'middle' });
    $("#<%=imgDateOfBirth.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        $('#<%=txtDateOfBirth.ClientID %>').datepicker('show');
    });
});
```

i was applied css also

all this is in content place holder

Comment: calendar css not changing as display block

Comment: when i seen in inspect element its not changing as 'displa:block'

Comment: now check to your path ......

Comment: s i had given correctly in my page

Comment: Hi @Sam can u show live path of this projects

Comment: sorry this is a local server i don't have live server for this

Comment: If in your page folder you have a folder named "scripts" then the path is ok, but I guess it is not.

Comment: i had given path correctly that's not a problem u can see in image all the code is appearing but display property only not changing

Answer (score 0):

I would start with just making sure that your datepicker is working.  Take off all the custom configs, css, and click handler (doesn't it already show by itself when you click, without adding a click handler?).  If it doesn't work with just $("#element").datepicker(), you have problems elsewhere.  Make sure that you have the appropriate jQuery files loaded (js and CSS).  Best of luck!